Past perfect tenses
Is there a way for us to use the past perfect simple tense twice in the same sentence ? For instance, "I had left my phone at home but I had brought my laptop." And how do we know which of these two actions happened first ?

The verb tenses in...

I had left my phone at home but I had brought my laptop

..are nothing to do with Which action happened first? The only reason you might use the Past Perfect form at all here is if your current "narrative time context" is already in the past. For example...

1: When I visited my parents yesterday, I had trouble contacting my girlfriend. I had left my phone at home but I had brought my laptop, so I was able to contact her through Facebook instead of calling her phone.

If your narrative context isn't already in the past...

2: Mum, can I invite my girlfriend to join us for dinner? I left my phone at home but I brought my laptop, so I will be able to contact her through Facebook instead of calling her phone.

It's possible to use Present Perfect in the second scenario, (have left, have brought), but I don't really see much point.
